# Нормализация таблицы для расчета среднего значения

Tags: sql, sql-server

коллеги, добрый день.
Имеется таблица :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Стоит задача посчитать среднее значение товара в пути в разрезе транспорта. Я понимаю, что таблицу нужно привести к следующему виду, чтобы время отбытия и время прибытия были в одной строке:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мои мысли были следующие, я создал временную таблицу и в неё хотел курсором внести данные с применением функции LEAD:

```
CREATE TABLE #MyTable1  (prod_id int, DepDate datetime,ArvDate datetime)
DECLARE @DepDate datetime, @ArvDate datetime , @prod_id int
DECLARE MyCursor1 CURSOR
FOR
Select id,date from roads
Open MyCursor1
FETCH NEXT FROM MyCursor1 INTO  @prod_id,@DepDate
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
BEGIN 
INSERT INTO #MyTable1 (prod_id,DepDate,ArvDate)
  VALUES (@prod_id,@DepDate,@ArvDate) 
  set @ArvDate =  LEAD (@DepDate) OVER (ORDER BY @DepDate)
FETCH NEXT FROM MyCursor1 INTO @prod_id,@Depdate
FETCH NEXT FROM MyCursor1 INTO @prod_id,@Depdate
END
CLOSE MyCursor1
DEALLOCATE MyCursor1
SELECT * FROM #MyTable1
DROP TABLE #MyTable1
```

Получается вот такая беда :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно еще решить?

Comment: *среднее значение товара в пути в разрезе транспорта* Поясните, что Вы хотели сказать этой загадочной фразой...

Comment: @Akina Это значит , что у продукта с Id=1 было три перемещения, нужно посчитать среднее время этих трех перемещений.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
WITH cte AS 
(
    SELECT id, Date DepDate, LEAD(Date) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY Date ASC) ArvDate, Reason
    FROM roads
)
SELECT id, DepDate, ArvDate,
FROM cte
WHERE Reason = 'Отбытие'
```

Конечно, запрос предполагает, что нет "зависших" записей. По-хорошему, надо вводить дополнительный контроль на это дело.

Доработать внешний запрос для подсчёта среднего, полагаю, несложно...

Comment: Спасибо. Нужно подтянуть оконные функции